# Erro no codigo java ler GSON: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, gson

Estou tentando ler este arquivo porém quando executo apresenta esse error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at principa.Main.main(Main.java:61)
```

porém não sei o que esta nulo

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Reader json;
        Gson gson = new Gson();

        try {
            json = new FileReader("C:/Users/rodrigo/original.txt");
            Profissao[] profissao = gson.fromJson(json, Profissao[].class);

            System.out.println(profissao[0].getHabilidades().get(0).getName());
            System.out.println(profissao[0].getDescricao());

            //Escrever no json
            Type type = new TypeToken<List<Profissao>>(){}.getType();
            List<Profissao> profissoes = gson.fromJson(json, type); //converte o json para uma lista

            System.out.println(profissoes);
            Profissao profissaoNova = new Profissao(); //cria uma nova profissao

            Local local = new Local();
            Habilidades hab = new Habilidades();

            profissaoNova.setDescricao("Encanador");

            local.setEndereco("Rua buquirinha 2");
            local.setTitle("Buquirinha 2");
            local.setlatitude(-23.2556945);
            local.setLongitude(-45.6995612);

            profissaoNova.getLocal().add(local);
            profissaoNova.getLocal().add(local);

            hab.setId(0);
            hab.setName("feliz");
            profissaoNova.getHabilidades().add(hab);

            System.out.println(profissaoNova.getHabilidades().get(0).getName());

            profissoes.add(profissaoNova); //adiciona a profissao no array

            String jsonString = gson.toJson(profissoes); //transforma para json novamente

            System.out.println(jsonString);

            Object[] Aprofissoes = profissoes.toArray();

            FileWriter writer;
            try {
                writer = new FileWriter("C:/Users/rodrigo/teste.txt");
                writer.write(jsonString);
                writer.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }
}
```

Em relação a meu *JSON* é este aqui

```
[
  {
    "descricao": "Professor",
    "local": [
      {
        "latitude": -23.1843473,
        "longitude": -45.8840718,
        "title": "Microcamp",
        "endereco": "rua vilaça 2010"
      },
      {
        "latitude": -23.1843473,
        "longitude": -45.8840718,
        "title": "Microcamp",
        "endereco": "rua vilaça 2010"
      }
    ],
    "habilidades":[
        {
          "id":0,
          "name":"fotografo"
        },
        {
          "id":1,
          "name":"escritor"
        }
      ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Qual é a linha 61?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como você não declarou qual é a linha 61, e também não inicializou a collection de *Local*, vou assumir que a linha 61 é essa onde está a primeira linha desse tipo abaixo. A solução é inicializar a collection.

```
profissaoNova.getLocal().add(local);
```

Além disso, onde você está convertendo o json para uma lista, vocês está tendo custo computacional com todo o processamento necessário para converter o JSON novamente.
O ideal seria vocês simplesmente se utilizar da conversão anterior, como abaixo:

```
List<Profissao> profissoes = Arrays.asList(profissao);
```